# Java: error: release version 13 not supported

Tags: java

My application is as simple as it can get:

`System.out.println("Hello World!")`

Results in:

`Error: java: error: release versoin 13 not supported`

Comment: What version of java do you have installed and how are you running your program? The simplest way to work with java is to install the JDK and compile using `javac`, run stuff using `java` on the command line. As release 13 is planned to release in September, you are probably doing something else, possibly involving time machines. :) Can you decribe your steps?

Comment: Hi, 
:):):)
I have version 12.0.1
Using IntelliJ IDEA
not sure if that helps

Comment: Well, if you have Java 12, then you can not use features of Java 13... You must have specified configuration somewhere that causes IntelliJ to try and use Java 13 features.

Comment: At the level of detail you provided so far, the only answer you are likely to get is "cannot reproduce". I can only speculate that you somehow managed to misconfigure your project to use java 13, try going through the project properties.

Comment: Sorry guys, as I said, I'm very new to this as well as community chats and appreciate your help. Is there a way to attach a file or send screen shot. I've checked the Project structure, and the only option that gives the lease errors is X-Experimental features. I have no idea where to check for any other setups

Comment: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Project Bytecode Version. This worked for me. You can also check Edit Configuration which in under Run Menu

Answer (score 18):

There's a  lot of places you must check:

- File -> Project Structure
- Edit Configurations (in drop down near RUN button)
- File -> Settings -> search for SDK

But what really worked for me after set everything above to my correctly Java 11 version was change this setting:

- File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Copiler -> Project Bytecode Version

This setting was pointing to Java 13, so I changed to Java 11 and everything started to work as expected

Good luck

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me was setting the language level to 13.

Go to File --> Project Structure --> Modules

Answer (score 5):

As @MNEMO shared, the low down your target java version to under 13 will be working.
Seems only v11 JDK added to your intelliJ.
But if you are stilling targeting to Java v13 or your project requires v13 then you can add the JDK to your intelliJ

> **File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Project Settings**(nav) -> **Project** -> **Project SDK**

Just clicking the **New...** to add newer JDK to your intelliJ.
You can find the JDK at /Library/Java if you are using MacOS and installed java v13.

It works for me well.

Answer (score 3):

Try "File" menu >> "Project Structure..."

And then click "Project Settings >> Modules" on left side pane.

When selecting "Sources" tab on right-most pane,
you would see "Language level:" drop-down, and you might see "13" being selected.

Try switching it to 12 or lower, the Error should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I got my IntelliJ working by:

file/settings/java compiler; Module-> target bytecode version set to 8,9 or 10.

file/project structure SDK and language set to 11, 12 or 13

no need to add anything into the pom.xml file

Answer (score 2):

For a maven project, I got it to work, by specifying source and target version for `maven-compiler-plugin`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>13</source>
                <target>13</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error in IntelliJ, Above solutions didn't work for me, as I am using maven `3.6.3` in my project. Setting the proper jdk version (in my case, JDK-1.8) under maven profiles tool box, in IntelliJ, resolved my issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as "Error : java: error: invalid source release: 13" and it is not related to "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Copiler -> Project Bytecode Version" as memtioned by others.

In IJ, there is 2 level of compiler setup, one is on system-level, another one is at your own project level. You must make a change in "Project Settings --> Project --> Project language level".

Thomas